# VBA - Nested "For Each" loops continuously

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, nested

I have two documents open at the same time, one is a blank template and the other is an old Excel file from which I am trying to transfer data into the new template format.  I am writing a macro to cycle through the designated column in the source file, and transfer over the value of any cells which are not blank.  This is my current code:

```
For Each TargetCell In RevisedFAA.Sheets("Repair Instruction").Range("K17:W40") 'Template
        For Each SourceCell In Range(FAA_User.AppColumn1.Value) 'Source file range

CheckSource:
        If SourceCell = "" Then 
            GoTo NextSourceCell 'if the cell in the source file is blank, skip to the next cell
        Else
            TargetCell.Value = SourceCell.Value
            GoTo NextTargetCell 'if the cell in the source file has data, transfer that data over to the template.
        End If
NextSourceCell:
        Next SourceCell

NextTargetCell:
        Next TargetCell
        GoTo NextSourceCell
```

The problem is when there is data in the source file, it transfers over to the template and then the loops repeats due to my `Next TargetCell` line, which sets the value of all the blank cells in the template to the first `SourceCell` with data.  Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run one loop, plus one increment, your code structure is going to be much simpler:

```
Dim lLoop As Long, lMaxLoop As Long, rgTarget As Range
Dim sourceCell As Range

Set rgTarget = RevisedFAA.Sheets("Repair Instruction").Range("K17:W40")
lLoop = 1

Set lMaxLoop = rgTarget.Cells.Count

For Each sourceCell In Range(FAA_User.AppColumn1.Value) 'Source file range

    If sourceCell <> "" Then
        rgTarget.Cells(lLoop).Value = sourceCell.Value
        lLoop = lLoop + 1
        If lLoop > lMaxLoop Then Exit For
    End If

Next sourceCell
```

Comment: @nutsch Thank you for the suggestion!  For some reason I am receiving an "Object required" error at the `1Loop = 1` line, or in my case `i = 1`.

Comment: @CJK remove "set" from that line. You only use set with objects, not basic variable types.

Comment: @enderland Thank you for the comment, that has removed the object error!  The only other problem I am running into now is the `rgTarget.Cells(...)` line, because the cells I am selecting are merged (i.e. the range "K17:W40" only has 12 merged cells), thus when `lLoop` is equal to 2, it is selecting the second cell in the range, not the next merged cell.

Comment: @enderland Nevermind, I just changed the integer in `lLoop = lLoop + 1` to a number that skips all the other cells (even though it looks awkward).  Thank you again for your help!